# Выделение памяти под константы

Tags: javascript

Есть код, работающий в браузере:

```
export const AuthService = {
  auth(user) {
    const config = {
      baseURL: API_URL,
      headers: {
        post: {
          "Content-Type": 'application/json',
        },
      },
    };
    const instance = axios.create(config);
    return instance.post("/token", user);
  }
};
```

Сколько раз выделится память под config, если auth будет вызвана десять раз? Можно ли как-то оптимизировать данный код, чтобы (не знаю, есть ли такая вещь, как private static в javascript) было оптимальнее по расходу выделяемой памяти?

Comment: второй вариант не работает :-)

Comment: Ага :-) 100% :-) как минимум `this.config` в строке `instance: axios.create(this.config),` это не свойство `AuthService`. Да и `this` в этом случае скорее всего на `module` ссылается, то есть вероятно где-то еще объявлена переменная `config`. Кстати проверить очень просто: закомментируй свойство `config`

Comment: То есть это практически то же самое, что и дефолтный конфиг `instance: axios.create(),` и работает по чистому недоразумению (конфиг почти такой же как дефолтный)?

Comment: Ну скорее `axios.create(undefined)` - может быть там один параметр как-то обрабатывается

Comment: Ну кстати проверить можно по урлу на который все отправляется. Но да, то что работает - это случайность :)

Comment: формально можно сделать `const onfig = {...}` до `export`, а в export, тогда переменная создастся один раз при экспорте модуля и в принципе не будет доступна нигде кроме `auth` и внутри модуля

Comment: Но что-то мне подсказывает, что это не сильно поможет с расходом памяти :-)